# Active Directory using Samba/Open LDAP for user accounts

Tags: samba, active-directory, openldap

I know this is the wrong way round... but

Is it possible to use AD in front of Samba for our PC clients, so that the user accounts are in Samba/Open LDAP.

Managing our fleet of Windows PC's is becoming more and more difficult with just Samba v3 - until Samba v4 comes along, it would be great if we could leverage Active Directory, but have the accounts stored in Samba/Open LDAP.

Windows PC's are a minority in our organisation & Samaba/Open LDAP are used for just about every service (Zimbra/RADIUS/Intranet/SAN/Printing/...) so it will have to remain the definitive account source.  Anyway, it probably can't be done, but I thought I would ask for ideas anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't got any experience actually doing this, but it sure seems technically feasible to set up an Active Directory forest to join the computers into while preserving the ability to logon with the existing Samba domain accounts. They key is creating an NT 4 style trust relationship between the Samba domain and the Active Directory domain (either two-way, or with the AD domain trusting the Samba domain in a one-way trust) to allow the existing Samba domain user accounts to logon to these computers.

It should be a transparent process for the users. You'll be able to add computers to the AD domain at your leisure.

The main issues I can think of that might crop up during the creation of the trust would be good NetBIOS name resolution. I'd run a WINS server, either on the Samba DCs or on the Windows DCs, and have both the client and server computers register themselves. That ought to save a lot of heartburn fighting name resolution issues.

Comment: Sounds good - will give it a try!

Answer (score -1):

Can you share any notes from your trial?

---

--------- **Update1**

**@whatever-downvoted-my-answer, be it bot or human,**

May I ask why my questions were downvoted? Uncommented / unexplained, i.e. unreasonable, downvotes disservice and discredit the community of serverfault.com

Comment: Hmm, in 2 min upon posting I have got "-1". What does it mean, I wonder?

Comment: -1:  More appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @vgv8:  The FAQ is your friend:  http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: No comment was available. I think it is connected with the period of inactivity of the thread. Though please continue, I am hoping to hit the negative maximum

Comment: I read over : serverfault.com/faq again. What was it for? I could not post any comment, and there is no clarification on my asking to share with experience in this topic

Comment: It's very simple: this doesn't look like an answer. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, create awesome questions and answers to gain reputation to allow you to add comments.